# Oracle accepting the recommended SQL profile

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a query that I want to optimize in Oracle SQL Developer. On a Worksheet I write my query and I click SQL Tuning Advisor and it returns me a result as :

```
  Recommendation (estimated benefit: 82.8%)
  -----------------------------------------  
- Consider accepting the recommended SQL profile.
  execute dbms_sqltune.accept_sql_profile(task_name => 'staName51544',
  task_owner => 'sa', replace => TRUE);
```

I run the `execute` command and I get this result:

'PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.'

Can you show me how do I view the result of this execution ?

EDIT :
I have run this query :

```
COLUMN category FORMAT a10
COLUMN sql_text FORMAT a20
SELECT NAME,type, SQL_TEXT, CATEGORY, STATUS FROM DBA_SQL_PROFILES;
```

but the SQL_TEXT here is exactly same as my query

Comment: that does not return a result.

Comment: I am beginner with Oracle, can you show me please how can I view the optimized Query ?

Comment: Show the query.  Did you run an explain plan on the query?  How do you know there is anything to optimize?

Comment: yes it says `Recommendation (estimated benefit: 82.8%)`

Comment: Check in ```gv$sql```. You should see SQL_ID taking SQL profile. ```select inst_id,sql_id, sql_profile from gv$sql where sql_id = 'whateversqlid profile was applied to'; ```

Comment: Hi Pankaj, ok I see the SQL_Id, so what should I do with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your question:

> Can you show me how do I view the result of this execution ?

if you see your query on DBA_SQL_PROFILES, it means that a SQL Profile was created for your query, that's the purpose of the dbms_sqltune.accept_sql_profile procedure.

Indeed, a SQL Profile is based on your exact same query text, and Oracle will use it the next time the query is executed, which might( Or might not) improve your query execution plan.

I have the impression that you think that oracle will rewrite your query, that's not the case, a profile will just store attributes and statistics that oracle will use to run your query the next time